# To what extent are technology transfers weighted when reviewing a professor's tenure application in a US university?

Tags: tenure-track, industry

I wonder to what extent [technology transfers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technology_transfer) are weighted when reviewing a professor's tenure application in a US university. E.g. in the case that a professor collaborated, possibly via one of their PhD students, to a technology transfer performed within some private enterprise, e.g. deplying an algorithm developed/advised by/etc. by the professor and their PhD student into a product/program of this entreprise.

Comment: I don't really have any experience here, but I would suspect that this varies a lot between universities and between different departments/subject areas within universities. Is this really a question that has a general answer?

Comment: @avid thanks, in this case I'm interested in computer science > natural language processing or computer vision.

Comment: Technology transfer seems hard to quantify. Something like a patent is more objective and I know that carries some weight.

Answer (score 4):

To expand on @Buffy's question:

In many ways, each tenure and promotion case is different from all others. Professors are evaluated with regards to many criteria:

- Number of papers
- Grants received
- Patents
- Tech transfer
- Quality of teaching
- Number of graduate students and how they did
- Service in the department
- Service in the university
- Outside service
- Conference organization
- Mentorship of graduate students, postdocs, and younger colleagues
- ...

How each of these is weighted depends on the university, department, and the field you're in, but the key point I want to make is this: Most cases are not "obvious" in the sense that the candidate is excellent in all of these areas. Everyone has their own foci and most candidates are good in some areas and maybe not so rounded in others. The challenge in deciding whether there is one or a few areas where a candidate is really good, and good enough in the others.

What that one area (or these few areas) are will be different from candidate to candidate, and is something that as a candidate is worth working out for yourself. In essence, you'll have to make the case why you're worth getting tenure or getting promoted, and that's why (i) talking to senior colleagues, (ii) your research, teaching, and service statements matter.

In other words, tech transfer *can* be an important piece of the puzzle if it fits into the areas of strength of a candidate, and I could imagine it being a key criterion a department takes into account even in areas where tech transfer is uncommon. On the other hand, if you don't have a lot going on in research, but you're a good teacher, and then there's the one-time $10k fee a company paid to use something you came up with, then the latter is probably not going to carry much weight: It looks like a one-time thing, and people will not consider it as a big deal. A part of the consideration here is that giving someone tenure isn't just a judgment on a candidate's *past* work, but just as much about the *future prospects* of that person, and something that looked like a one-time thing just isn't going to give much of a boost.

Answer (score 2):

Like a lot of things in academia, this depends on the field, the university, and the individual professor. It can be very important in, say, medicine or engineering, but less so in others. Some universities (Stanford, for example) built quite a reputation for this and fostered the development of important technology and its spread. This is why "Silicon Valley" exists, actually.

If you want to make it count in your own application, of course, you need to make the case for it. But that might be like anything else.

If you mean applying for actual tenure (rather than for a TT position), then you need to convince your colleagues who will likely have a say in your application, as well as your Dean. This will be more natural some places than others. If you are an outlier, then it probably has less effect than if others do similar things.